# How to hook into field creation (form successfully processed)?

Tags: entities, 8

I need to act after field has been created (new db table).
Actually I need to use data from the first field form: 
field-ui-field-storage-add-form
So ideally I need to hook on this form being successfully processed (and its data).
Is there any way of achieving it?
Something like old hook_field_storage_create_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field storage configs and field configs are config entities hand have the standard hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/insert/update/delete() hooks.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert() for 'field_storage_config'.
 */
function comment_field_storage_config_insert(FieldStorageConfigInterface $field_storage) {
}
```

Comment: How could I not came up with it ;) Excellent. Thanks.